# Injecting vault secrets into Kubernetes Pod Environment variable

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, sonarqube, hashicorp-vault, kubernetes-secrets

I'm trying to install Sonarqube in Kubernetes environment which needs PostgresSQL.
I'm using an external Postgres instance and I have the credentials kv secret set in Vault.
SonarQube helm chart creates an Environment variable in the container which takes the username and password for Postgres.

How can I inject the secret from my Vault to environment variable of sonarqube pod running on Kubernetes?

Creating a Kubernetes secret and using the secret in the helm chart works, but we are managing all secrets on Vault and need Vault secrets to be injected into pods.

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

There are 2 ways to inject vault secrets into the k8s pod as ENV vars.

## 1) Use the vault Agent Injector

A template should be created that exports a Vault secret as an environment variable.

```
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        # Environment variable export template
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-config: |
          {{ with secret "secret/data/web" -}}
            export api_key="{{ .Data.data.payments_api_key }}"
          {{- end }}
```

And the application container should source those files during startup.

```
args:
  ['sh', '-c', 'source /vault/secrets/config && <entrypoint script>']
```

Reference: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/platform/k8s/injector/examples#environment-variable-example

## 2) Use banzaicloud bank-vault

Reference: https://banzaicloud.com/blog/inject-secrets-into-pods-vault-revisited/.

## Comments:

Both methods are bypassing k8s security because secrets are not stored in etcd.
In addition, pods are unaware of vault in both methods.
So any one of these can be adopted without a deep comparison.

**For vault-k8s and vault-helm users, I recommend the first method.**

Answer (score 4):

I want to propose a solution which doesn't require hijacking the entrypoint of the container, which is difficult to generalize across deployments, and requires manual intervention each time.

It is quite similar to the accepted answer.

First, you render your secret with an export-statement:

```
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        # Environment variable export template
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-config: |
          {{ with secret "secret/data/web" -}}
            export api_key="{{ .Data.data.payments_api_key }}"
          {{- end }}
```

Then you can override the pods `BASH_ENV` to make sure this file is sourced at startup:

```
template:
  spec:
    containers:
      - env:
        - name: BASH_ENV
          value: /vault/secrets/config
```

This works because the `BASH_ENV` variable determines which file is sourced at startup of a non-login shell [0]

If you need to export several variables, you need to get a bit more creative with templating, or setting the `BASH_ENV` variable, but it should be possible.

References:

0: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-BASH_005fENV

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a parent process that will talk to vault and retrieve the value, and then run your real process. https://github.com/hashicorp/envconsul is the marginally official tool for this from the Vault team, but there are many other options if you go looking.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1 Official Vault**

Full answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73046067

```
annotations:
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-image: <Agent image>
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: "true"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-secrets: kv/<Path-of-secret>
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-secrets: |2

          {{- with secret "kv/<Path-of-secret>" -}}

          #!/bin/sh
          set -e

          {{- range $key, $value := .Data.data }}
          export {{ $key }}={{ $value }}
          {{- end }}

          exec "$@"
          {{- end }}
        vault.hashicorp.com/auth-path: auth/<K8s cluster for auth>
        vault.hashicorp.com/role: app
```

**Option 2 Third party**

If you are facing issue in injecting secret using consul sidecar container and finding it very difficult to setup you can use this : https://github.com/DaspawnW/vault-crd

This is vault-custom resource definition which directly sync vault environment variables to kuberntes secret so now you can directly add secret to POD. with `secretref`.

vault crd create one pod in which you have to pass vault service name or URL using which application can connect to vault and on changes in vault value it will automatically sync value to kubernetes secret.

https://vault.koudingspawn.de/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that could provide some insight: https://banzaicloud.com/blog/inject-secrets-into-pods-vault-revisited/#kubernetes-mutating-webhook-for-injecting-secrets

Comment: Welcome Flash1212 and thanks for this answer! Could you provide some context for the link, please? (cf. the "Provide context for links" of the "How to answer" guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my deployment had the following annotation:

```yaml
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-configmap: my-configmap
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-extra-secret: something
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: "true"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-pre-populate-only: "true"
```

In my case, I needed to load the variables from `/vault/secrets/myfile.env`.

I tried using `['sh', '-c', 'source /vault/secrets/myfile.env && <entrypoint script>']`, with no luck.
What worked for me was using `['sh', '-c', 'export $(cat /vault/secrets/myfile.env | xargs) && <entrypoint script>']`.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76761424/10215243

###### _vault_helpers.tpl

```
{{- define "release-name.vaultPodAnnotations" -}}
# Other annotations
{{- range $secret := .Values.vault.secrets }}
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-{{ $secret.name }}: ""
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-{{ $secret.name }}: {{ $secret.template | quote }}
{{- end }}
# Other annotations
{{- end }}
```

###### deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: foo-bar
  labels:
    foo: bar
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      foo: bar
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        {{- include "release-name.vaultPodAnnotations" . | nindent 8 }}
      labels:
        foo: bar
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: foo-bar
        labelSelector: 
          matchLabels:
            foo: bar
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
        - name: foo-bar
          image: foo-bar
          env:
            - name: ENV
              value: /vault/secrets/env_var.sh
```

###### values.yaml

```
# Other Values

vault:
  secrets:
    - name: env_var.sh
      template: |
        #!/bin/sh
        set -e
        export api_key="{{- with secret "secret/data/web" -}}{{ .Data.data.payments_api_key }}{{- end -}}"
        export other_secrets="{{- with secret "secret/data/other-secrets" -}}{{ .Data.data.other_secrets }}{{- end -}}"

# Other Values
```

If the container's shell is BASH, set the environment variable using `BASH_ENV`. For SH shells, use `ENV`.

Using the instructions provided above, you can expose multiple secrets by specifying a file and then expose the script using either the `ENV` or `BASH_ENV` variable.