Injecting sensitive information to Helm Charts via Vault
I would like to deploy a service to Kubernetes with a public Helm Chart from Artifacthub.
How could I inject sensitive information with Vault?

Can you elaborate more? which information exactly you want to inject and to where?

Remember that Helm stores its state in more-or-less-readable Kubernetes Secrets, and you can helm get values something that's been previously installed.  Is injecting the secrets to Helm appropriate?  What have you tried already and what problems are you running into?

My thought was doing it similar to this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66057099/2386605 . I don't know how to do it without environment variables?
